# Android Studio Shared Preferences Set Font Style

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, mobile-development

Currently I'm trying to get the input choice from List Preference which has (Italic, Bold, Underlined) styles in it, but I am not quite sure how to accomplished this specifically.

In the past, I've successfully done it for font type, size and colors.

Font Type Example:

```
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String s = sharedPreferences.getString("font_list", "gnuolane rg.ttf");
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" + s);
    editText.setTypeface(face);
```

Font Size Example:

```
         String s2 = sharedPreferences.getString("font_size", "8");
    editText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(s2))
```

How can I achieve the same idea but with font styles, such as Bold, Italic, Underlined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int font_face = sharedPreferences.getInt("font_face", Typeface.NORMAL);
editText.setTypeface(Integer.toString(font_face));
```

Basically `Typeface.BOLD`, `Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC`, `Typeface.ITALIC`, `Typeface.NORMAL` is int as [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) said.

Comment: complains about the line "Typeface.NORMAL" for some reason

Comment: Sorry, I fixed `getString` to `getInt` now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Store Font Style**

```
private void storeFontStyle(int style){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("font_face", style);

        editor.apply();

    }
```

**Get font Style**

```
private int getFontStyle(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int font_face = sharedPreferences.getInt("font_face", Typeface.NORMAL);

    return font_face;
}
```

**Access Font Style**

```
int font_face=getFontStyle();

    editText.setTypeface(null, font_face);
```

Comment: It's complaining on "Typeface.Normal" and on "Integer.toString(font_face));

Comment: since i guess share preferences cant take int as second parameter

Comment: have you check this?

Comment: Yeah. and it makes the app crash

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the question for **BOLD** and *ITALIC* (I don't think it is possible to specifically underline *EditText*, but I might be wrong):

```
String fontSize = sharedPreferences.getString("font_size", "8");
String style= sharedPreferences.getInt("font_style", TypeFace.NORMAL);
String font = sharedPreferences.getString("font_list", "gnuolane rg.ttf");
Typeface face = Typeface.create(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" + s),style);
editText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(fontSize ))
```

As you can see, the style is just an *integer* variable inside *Typeface* that can be read via `editText.getTypeface().getStyle()` (and then saved to the *sharedPreferences*).

Possible values for the style are:

```
Typeface.NORMAL
Typeface.BOLD
Typeface.ITALIC
Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC
```

But in order for this to work you have to make sure that the asset you are creating your font from supports the different font styles (which is normally not the case to my knowledge).